# What can we do in order to find customers that follow a specific pre-defined pattern?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, statistics, optimization, hypothesis-testing

Let's say I have a few customers buying product A. How can I find other customers that have the same characteristics, or something close to, these A buyers?

I was thinking about using clustering methods, but I don't know if it's possible to "lock" some characteristic (for instance, putting all customers that have the locked characteristic in the same cluster).

To sum up, the question would be: is there any way of finding similar customers to a pre-selected group?

Comment: Couldn't you just run kmodes?

Answer (score 0):

One way is nearest neighobor search. "Nearest" has to be defined, typically through a distance metric. Distance metrics depend on how the data is measured. If the data is measured continuously then [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) can be used. Often customer data is categorical. For categorical data, [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) can be used. There are many other distance metrics.